# traverse a nested js object to see if a search word/phrase is contained within one its keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

I'm having a heck of time trying to figure out how to write a JavaScript function that can traverse a nested JSON object looking to see if a user-supplied word and/or phrase is included within a couple of its keys.

The object is set up like the following:

```
{
  category_name: [{ 
    service: 'This is the name of the service.', 
    link: 'link to the service', 
    keywords: ['one', 'two', 'three']
  }, { 
    service: 'This is the name of another service.', 
    link: 'link to the other service', 
    keywords: ['one', 'four', 'six']
  }],
  category_name2: [{ 
    service: 'This is the name of the service.', 
    link: 'link to the service', 
    keywords: ['one', 'two', 'three']
  }, { 
    service: 'This is the name of another service.', 
    link: 'link to the other service', 
    keywords: ['one', 'four', 'six']
  }]
}
```

What I'm trying to get back is something like this:

If someone searches for the word "four" then the JavaScript function would search through all the "service" and "keywords" data fields to see if there is a match and, in this example, it would return all instances where the search word appears:

```
{
  category_name: [{
     service: "This is the name of another service.",
     link: "link to the other service",
     keywords: ["one", "four", "six"]
  }],
  category_name2: [{
    service: "This is the name of another service.",
    link: "link to the other service",
    keywords: ["one", "four", "six"]
  }],
}
```

Thank you to any help you can provide.

Comment: Please share some of your attempts.  What goes wrong when you try this yourself?

Comment: So you're not really looking to match keys - you're checking if it's contained in the `keywords` property's value.

Comment: It needs to check if the 'word/phrase' is contained in either the 'service' property's value and/or the 'keywords' property's value.

Comment: @R.Tuttle Partial matches or exact word matches? I.e. would "car" match "cart", "carnival", etc. or do you only want it to match the exact term given?

Comment: partial match is fine

Comment: Check out my answer below, it allows for partial matches and checks both services and keywords for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: That’s not JSON, etc etc

Comment: To Expand on what James said @R.Tuttle, JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation. It is a way to represent a Javascript Object as a string. This is not JSON. There is no such thing as a JSON object. This is a Javascript Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the user's input should check both the `service` and the `keywords` inclusively. Thus, a filter and find will do the job.

```js
      function search(data, value) {
            let keys = Object.keys(data);
            let result = keys.map((key)=>{
              let result = data[key].filter((obj) => {
              let has_service = obj.service.match(value);
              if (has_service) return obj;
              // console.log(has_service)
              let has_keyword = obj.keywords.find((key) => {
                let result = key.match(value)
                return result;
              });
              if (has_keyword) return obj;
            });
             if(result.length)
                return { [key] : result };
             return [];
            }).reduce((A, B)=>{ return A.concat(B) }, []);
           return result;
          }

      var data = {
              "category_name": [
                { "service": "This is the name of the service.", "link": "link to the service", "keywords": ["one", "two", "three"]},
              { "service": "This is the name of another service.", "link": "link to the other service", "keywords": ["one", "four", "six"]}
              ], 
             "category_name2": [
               { "service": "This is the name of the service.", "link": "link to the service", "keywords": ["one", "two", "three"]},
              { "service": "Yet another service.", "link": "link to the other service", "keywords": ["seven", "four", "six"]}
             ]
          };

        console.log(search(data, "four"))
```

Comment: `key` in `keywords.find()` would be a string, so `key.find()` would produce an error

Comment: Thats not true. match works for both strings and regular expressions. Also, i've ammended my answer to have the correct `.find` only a single time instead of twice. that was a typo. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ah, true - I forgot about the implicit conversion to regexp if the value passed in to `.match()` is a string or number.

Comment: lol. trust me... I had to check myself before posting. I wasnt sure, until i opened my console. So its an honest mistake to forget for sure.

Comment: JavaScript: The language that keeps on giving `;)`

Comment: For sure... at least it isnt  as egregious as `.1 + .2`

Comment: it's setup like this: "category_name": [{ "service": "This is the name of the service.", "link": "link to the service", "keywords": ["one", "two", "three"]}, { "service": "This is the name of another service.", "link": "link to the other service", "keywords": ["one", "four", "six"]}] },"category_name2": [{ "service": "This is the name of the service.", "link": "link to the service", "keywords": ["one", "two", "three"]}, { "service": "This is the name of another service.", "link": "link to the other service", "keywords": ["one", "four", "six"]}] }

Comment: I'm guessing you want it to query any category to be found on the object, which could be any `n` amount of category keys? if so, i'll make a new edit to reflect that. we would simply just need to get the `Object.keys` of your object first, then map over it in the same way.

Comment: @R.Tuttle I've editted my answer to reflect an object, which could have `n` number of category keys as your object seems to do. Hope that helps.

Comment: @JaSuperior In all fairness to JS, that is IEEE 754 standard floating point arithmetic. Works that way in just about every major language out there

Comment: @R.Tuttle also, i've editted the search function to take your input `data` object as a param. This will make it extensible for use with other objects as well.

Comment: @mhodges I know... -_- but given all of the optimizations js does for other data types, you'd think they'd perhaps just account for this as an exception in the runtime, and produce the proper answer when one runs into these floating point anomalies.

Comment: are you inputing the `data` object into the `search()` function as the first parameter? When using the `search()` function, you should call it as follows `search(data, term)` where `data` is your object and `term` is the term being searched.

Comment: @R.Tuttle sorry, i didnt mention you in that last comment

Comment: @R.Tuttle could you perhaps, post your code exactly as you are writing it, including your data object? As you can see above, if your object was formatted as you've described you should have no issue. perhaps, there is something else which you've perhaps not mentioned/noticed.

Comment: just noticed that it's not returning the main 'category_name' along with the other results... is there a way to do that?

Comment: @JaSuperior any additional thoughts on how to include the "category_name" key along with the values found via the search term?

Comment: @R.Tuttle i editted my answer to include the category that the data came from. hope thats what you were asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by making use of the `.filter()` method on an array. You can test it against a condition (is the term found in the keywords array) and if it returns true, it includes the item, if not, it excludes it - like so:

```js
var data = {
  "category_name": [{
      "service": "This is the name of the service.",
      "link": "link to the service",
      "keywords": ["one", "two", "three"]
    }, {
      "service": "This is the name of another service.",
      "link": "link to the other service",
      "keywords": ["one", "four", "six"]
    }],
  "category_name2": [{
    "service": "This is the name of the service.",
    "link": "link to the service",
    "keywords": ["one", "two", "three"]
  }, {
    "service": "This is the name of another service.",
    "link": "link to the other service",
    "keywords": ["one", "four", "six"]
  }]
}

function searchProp(data, prop, searchValue) {
  return data[prop].filter(category => category.keywords.includes(searchValue) || category.service.indexOf(searchValue) > -1);
}

function searchData(value) {
  return Object.keys(data).filter(key => key.indexOf("category_name") > -1).reduce((res, currKey) => {
    var currVal = searchProp(data, currKey, value);
    if (currVal.length) {
      res[currKey] = currVal;
    }
    return res;
  }, {})
}

console.log(searchData("four"));
console.log(searchData("one"));
console.log(searchData("another"));
```

Comment: How would this work if there are many different "category_name" properties as well?

Comment: @R.Tuttle Object properties are unique - I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you mean if it's an array of arrays?

Comment: it's setup like this: "category_name": [{ "service": "This is the name of the service.", "link": "link to the service", "keywords": ["one", "two", "three"]},
{ "service": "This is the name of another service.", "link": "link to the other service", "keywords": ["one", "four", "six"]}]
},"category_name2": [{ "service": "This is the name of the service.", "link": "link to the service", "keywords": ["one", "two", "three"]},
{ "service": "This is the name of another service.", "link": "link to the other service", "keywords": ["one", "four", "six"]}]
}

Comment: @R.Tuttle updated - take a look and let me know if that is what you were looking for

Comment: @R.Tuttle Side note - this snippet will show duplicates in the results because the sample data is duplicated. I'm assuming you wouldn't have to worry about this in your actual application, is that correct?

Comment: it looks good but when I try it in my codebase I am getting the following error instead: "TypeError: data[prop].filter is not a function".

Comment: @R.Tuttle That's because it's iterating over a property that's not an array. I would need to know what `data` actually looks like in order to properly select the keys. Will they always start with `category_name` and then just have a number appended to the end?

Comment: @R.Tuttle Try my updated solution that filters out keys that don't contain `"category_name"` using `.filter(key => key.indexOf("category_name") > -1)`

Comment: actually, where it states 'category_name' will just be different random categories: such as "accountancy", "transportation", etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate this into parts.  The first one, `mapObj`, is quite reusable.  This should demonstrate what it does.

```
const square = n => n * n
mapObj(square, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})  //=> {a: 1, b: 4, c: 9}
```

To use this, we can map our object with a filter call using a predicate like this:

```
const matchesTerm = (term) => {
  const rx = new RegExp(`\\b${term}\\b`, 'i') 
  return (svc) => svc.keywords.includes(term) || rx.test(svc.service)
}
```

Then this can be used in the main function as the predicate passed to filter, as so:

```
const findTerm = (data) => (term) =>
  mapObj((category) => category.filter(matchesTerm(term)), data)
```

I find that breaking the problem down like this helps me find common patterns (`mapObj`) and keep the design in my head better.

This makes the assumption that you want only whole matches in the keywords, but partial matches in the description.  But if that is not the case, it's easy to change the predicate.  It also is case-sensitive for the keywords, but insensitive for the descriptions.  Again, this can be changed readily.

---

You can see this in action:

```js
const mapObj = (fn, obj) => Object.keys(obj).reduce(
  (acc, key) => Object.assign(acc, {[key]: fn(obj[key])}),
  {}
)

const matchesTerm = (term) => {
  const rx = new RegExp(`${term}`, 'i') 
  return (svc) => svc.keywords.includes(term) || rx.test(svc.service)
}

const findTerm = (data) => (term) =>
  mapObj((category) => category.filter(matchesTerm(term)), data)

const data = {
  category_name1: [
    { 
      service: 'This is the name of the service.', 
      link: 'link to the service', 
      keywords: ['one', 'two', 'three']
    },
    { 
      service: 'This is the name of another service.', 
      link: 'link to the other service', 
      keywords: ['one', 'four', 'six']
    }
  ],
  category_name2: [
    { 
      service: 'This is the name of the service.', 
      link: 'link to the service', 
      keywords: ['one', 'two', 'three']
    },
    { 
      service: 'This is the name of another service.', 
      link: 'link to the other service', 
      keywords: ['one', 'four', 'six']
    }
  ]

}

console.log(findTerm(data)('four'))    // one match
console.log(findTerm(data)('one'))     // several matches
console.log(findTerm(data)('anoth'))   // partial match
console.log(findTerm(data)('missing')) // no match
```

---

### Update

A comment asked for a version without arrow functions.  This one replaces those with function expressions, and replaces `includes` with `indexOf(...) > -1`.  It does not offer [a shim for `Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill).  You would have to do that separately.

```js
const mapObj = function(fn, obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(
    function(acc, key) {
      const newObj = {};
      newObj[key] = fn(obj[key]);
      return Object.assign(acc, newObj)
    }, 
    {}
  )
}

const matchesTerm = function(term) {
  const rx = new RegExp(`${term}`, 'i') 
  return function(svc) {
    return svc.keywords.indexOf(term) > -1 || rx.test(svc.service)
  }
}

const findTerm = function(data) {
  return function(term) {
    return mapObj(function(category) {
      return category.filter(matchesTerm(term))
    }, data)
  }
}


const data = {"category_name1": [{"keywords": ["one", "two", "three"], "link": "link to the service", "service": "This is the name of the service."}, {"keywords": ["one", "four", "six"], "link": "link to the other service", "service": "This is the name of another service."}], "category_name2": [{"keywords": ["one", "two", "three"], "link": "link to the service", "service": "This is the name of the service."}, {"keywords": ["one", "four", "six"], "link": "link to the other service", "service": "This is the name of another service."}]}

console.log(findTerm(data)('four'))    // one match
console.log(findTerm(data)('one'))     // several matches
console.log(findTerm(data)('anoth'))   // partial match
console.log(findTerm(data)('missing')) // no match
```

Comment: This looks really good, but this code has to be run in an older browser that doesn't 'understand' arrow functions.  I've tried re-writing them to test out but it keeps failing on the call to mapObj. Thoughts?

Comment: Updated to change to function expressions.  The code doesn't feel nearly as clean!